# String with <> not correctly encoded

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

m.Value is a string like

```
"abc <xy-edf>"
```

I'm using it in

```
<%:Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Value)%>
```

Now, the html output is

```
value="abc &lt;xy-edf>"
```

So, the ending ">" was not correctly encoded resulting in a dangerous request...

Any hints, how to solve this issue?

Comment: You can even pass this data using `[AllowHtml]` attribute on Model Property

Answer (score 0):

This HTML is Encoded,

You can use

```
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Value);
```

Comment: What do you mean with encoded? The input string includes <...> but the output string &lt;...> meaning the string was only partially encoded.

Comment: You can't use methods in templates.
Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Comment: But you should use this in controller. and return that model

Comment: I don't want to alter the model in the controller. The model data is correct. The view is not encoding it properly.

Comment: Then use this `@Html.Raw(Model.Value)`